# Flow vs alert me

Tags: sharepoint-online, approval-process, microsoft-flow

Seems a dummy question:
But I have created an approval process for a list in MS flow, it does the approval and some other things. So, as soon as a user changes an item, I am supposed to receive an email with two options:approve and reject. Well there is no issue here, but the flow needs about 5 to 10 time to change to the running state. So, if the admin, approve/reject a change in the list immediately after a change (i.e. less than 5 min), then I am not sure that the flow will start or not, as I need that the designed flow always run as I have set other things in the flow to happen. It seems the flow runs whether admin has approved/rejected the item through "my submission". so, the admin should always do the approval through email, right?

Comment: If you have a set of actions that should occur after an item is approved, I would suggest having a separate Flow to perform those actions when an item is approved, that way, it won't matter what mechanism is used to approve.

Comment: So it does not matter, what mechanism I approve. it always run the flow, I appreciate if you post this as the answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed above in the comments:
If you have a set of actions that you need to occur after an item is approved, you should move those actions to a separate Flow.
Trigger the Flow on `Item Created or Modified`, then use a `Condition` action to check if the status is `Approved`, inside that conditional block is where you want to put all of your "post-approval" actions.

By doing this, it won't matter what mechanism is used to approve.  Whether the user waits for the Approval Flow and approves via email, or approves manually before the Flow runs, or even if you write code at some point to approve an item programmatically, the "after approval" Flow will always be triggered.